# Know any manufacturer of beeswax capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, manufacturing

Other than [Jupiter](http://jupitercondenser.com/cryo-ht-beeswax-paper-capacitors.html).
I need to replace a vintage beewax capacitor. I don't want other types of waxes.

Comment: I am sorry to say @user2534 that this question is not a good fit for out site. Ignoring all of the comments that were here(and not really constructive), the issue is that finding a supplier for a very specific rare type of component is in general a better job for google as it is more about finding whom current makes them and prices change constantly. I am sorry you had a negative experience with this question, but users were just trying to help you find a component that worked as they thought you may not need this kind of capacitor.

Comment: I'm disgusted by the fact that comments were removed. If anyone has copy of them all, upload the file and share the link thx. @Kortuk if I asked here it's because I already did a google search. There's no way a search engine can answer better than a bunch of experts, or this site would be closed down.

Comment: the site is to allow experts to answer questions, not tell you about current suppliers for parts. Those answers are inherently going to change with time. Google will update based on changes in suppliers, our questions wont without concerted effort. Sorry you dislike the comments being removed but they were not productive and comments are not important pieces of information, thus why we call them comments and not answers.

Comment: If you would like to discuss further come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/895/ee-ask-a-moderator). Please note you were already told this type of question was a poor fit for our site [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/42109/230). Continuing to ask questions that are a poor fit is abusive to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, [Aerovox](http://www.aerovox.com) makes beeswax capacitors. You may also google *bumblebee capacitors*.

FYI, you catch more flys with honey (or in this case you catch more bee capacitors,) so you may want to at least be helpfull with people who are trying to help you in your search!

Answer (score 1):

Hack a day [DIY foil caps](http://hackaday.com/2011/05/10/roll-your-own-capacitors-high-voltage-edition/) roll your own.

Searching for wax capacitors on ebay seems to produce some useful leads.
[Including these](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Lot-of-50-Vintage-wax-capacitors-many-NOS-caps-/261102762725?pt=Vintage_Electronics_R2&hash=item3ccaeffae5)

[image: http://i.ebayimg.com/t/Lot-of-50-Vintage-wax-capacitors-many-NOS-caps-/00/s/MTYwMFgxMDQ3/$(KGrHqJ,!noFBc4hoJe)BQ()kKop0Q~~60_57.JPG]

Comment: But nobody manufactures one or the other.